# “invalid configuration argument” error when calling CUDA kernel

Tags: cuda, gpu

I have GeForce 620M and my code is:

```
int threadsPerBlock = 256;                  
int blocksPerGrid = Number_AA_GPU / threadsPerBlock; 
for(it=0;it<Number_repeatGPU;it++)
{
    Kernel_Update<<<blocksPerGrid,threadsPerBlock>>>(A, B, C, D, rand(), rand());     
}
```

I get:

> invalid configuration argument.

What could be the reason?

Comment: The reason probably depends on the value of `Number_AA_GPU`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kernel configuration arguments are the arguments between the `<<<...>>>` symbols.

Your GeForce 620M is a [compute capability 2.1](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus) device.

A compute capability 2.1 device [is limited to 65535](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#features-and-technical-specifications) when you pass a 1-dimensional parameter for the blocks per grid parameter (the first of the two arguments you are passing.)

Since the other parameter you are passing (256, `threadsPerBlock`) is definitely in-bounds, I conclude that your first parameter is out of bounds:

```
int blocksPerGrid = Number_AA_GPU / threadsPerBlock;
```

i.e. `Number_AA_GPU` is either greater than 65535*256 (greater than or equal to 65536*256 would trigger a failure), or it is zero (actually `Number_AA_GPU` less than 256 would fail, due to integer division), or it is negative.

In the future, you can write more easily decipherable questions if you provide a complete example.  In this case, telling us what `Number_AA_GPU` is could make my answer more definite.